# i made custom tag in jstl and threw Unfamiliar exception help me

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

i made a custom tag for using jstl
it have J_crypto.decrypt

this is declare

```
<%@ taglib uri="/resources/tld/util.tld" prefix="util"%>
```

and this is my tld file

```
<function>
        <name>jcrypto</name>
        <function-class>com.dabin.confirm.util.PhoneManager</function-class>
        <function-signature>
            java.lang.String jcrypto(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String)
        </function-signature>
    </function>
```

java

```
public static String jcrypto(String seq, String number){
        return J_Crypto.decrypt(Integer.parseInt(seq.split("-")[1]), number);
    }
```

and i use like this

```
${util:jcrypto(dto.work_cnum, dto.deb_nm)}
```

i think this must activate but threw exception

```
10월 31, 2014 10:16:01 오전 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
심각: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Method "jcrypto" for function "jcrypto" not found in class "com.dabin.confirm.util.PhoneManager"
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:51)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:409)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:181)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor$1MapperELVisitor.visit(Validator.java:1682)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ELNode$Function.accept(ELNode.java:131)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ELNode$Nodes.visit(ELNode.java:206)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ELNode$Visitor.visit(ELNode.java:248)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ELNode$Root.accept(ELNode.java:56)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ELNode$Nodes.visit(ELNode.java:206)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.getFunctionMapper(Validator.java:1691)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.prepareExpression(Validator.java:1559)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:721)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$ELExpression.accept(Node.java:958)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:866)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:866)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1782)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:653)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:647)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.template.work_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f4(work_jsp.java:194)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.template.work_jsp._jspService(work_jsp.java:100)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

i don't know what's wrong
this tld file have another 2 method 
but it doesn't matter.
i'm sure that path is right.

i'm sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the function is not the same in the `tld` file, and in java code.

In the `tld` file:

```
String jcrypto(Integer, String)
```

In the java code:

```
String jcrypto(String, String)
```